# Calcular días que faltan para cumpleaños

Tags: java, date

Tengo que mostrar cuantos días faltan para que cumpla años dada la fecha de nacimiento, tengo este código.

```
public class EjercicioJava {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    String nombre, papellido,sapellido,direccion,poblacion, foto;
    Integer telefono;


    Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Introduce nombre");
    nombre= entrada.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Introduce 1er apellido");
    papellido= entrada.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Introduce 2o apellido");
    sapellido= entrada.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Introduce dirección");
    direccion= entrada.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Introduce población");
    poblacion= entrada.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Introduzca telefono");
    telefono= entrada.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Introduce foto");
    foto= entrada.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Usted se llama "+nombre+ " " + papellido + " " + sapellido + " ,con dirección " +direccion + " ,/n vive en " +poblacion+ " y cumple años dentro de " + meses + " meses y " + dias + " dias");


}
```

}

Comment: Si no colocas la fecha en que nació es imposible

Comment: No se de que tipo es, por eso no la he puesto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo un método completo que calcula cuántos meses y días faltan para el próximo cumpleaños, determinando además si el cumpleaños es hoy.

El método sería este, el cual puedes perfeccionar, en cuanto a la forma de imprimir o devolver el cálculo del cumpleaños.

Maneja también las posibles excepciones, como fechas erróneas, de modo que la aplicación no se detenga en esos casos.

```
   /*
       *Método para calcular el cumpleaños
       *Se podría integrar a una clase utilitaria
       * @param birthDate (String) Una cadena con la fecha de nacimiento

    */
    static void calculateBirthDay(String birthDate){            
        try {
            /*Fecha actual*/
            LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    
            /*Fecha de nacimiento. Ambas formas son válidas*/
            LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.parse(birthDate);
            LocalDate nextBDay = birthday.withYear(today.getYear());
    
            /*Si el cumpleaños ya ocurrió este año, agrega 1 año*/
            if (nextBDay.isBefore(today) || nextBDay.isEqual(today)) {
                nextBDay = nextBDay.plusYears(1);
            }
    
            Period p = Period.between(today, nextBDay);
            long totalDias = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(today, nextBDay);
    
            /*Cuando totalDias=365 hoy es el cumpleaños*/
    
            if (totalDias == 365) {
    
                System.out.println("¡Su cumpleaños es hoy. Felicidades!");
    
            } else {
    
                System.out.println("Restan " + p.getMonths() + " meses, y "
                        + p.getDays() + " días para su próximo cumpleaños. ("
                        + totalDias + " días en total)");
            }
            
        }catch (DateTimeParseException exc) {
            System.out.printf("Error: %s no es una fecha válida!%n", birthDate);
        }              
    }
```

Para usarlo sería tan simple como hacer esto, veamos pruebas con varias fechas:

```
    calculateBirthDay("2008-10-30");
    calculateBirthDay("2008-10-31");
    /*Fecha errónea*/
    calculateBirthDay("2008-10-32");
```

**Salida de las tres pruebas:**

```
¡Su cumpleaños es hoy. Felicidades!
Restan 0 meses, y 1 días para su próximo cumpleaños. (1 días en total)
Error: 2008-10-32 no es una fecha válida!
```

---

#### Código de prueba

Puedes ver una prueba de código en Rextester: <kbd>**[VER DEMO](https://rextester.com/KIILV81212)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Necesitaria solicitar la fecha de nacimiento y restarle a la fecha actua, de esta manera:

```
import java.time.Period;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class EjercicioJava {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        String nombre, papellido,sapellido,direccion,poblacion,foto,nacimiento;
        int telefono;

        Scanner entrada= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Introduce nombre");
        nombre= entrada.nextLine();


        System.out.println("Introduce 1er apellido");
        papellido= entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduce 2o apellido");
        sapellido= entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduce dirección");
        direccion= entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduce población");
        poblacion= entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduzca fecha de nacimiento (dd/MM/yyyy)");
        nacimiento= entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduce foto");
        foto= entrada.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Introduzca telefono");
        telefono= entrada.nextInt();

        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
        LocalDate fechaNac = LocalDate.parse(nacimiento, fmt);
        LocalDate ahora = LocalDate.now();

        Period periodo = Period.between(fechaNac, ahora);

        System.out.println("Usted se llama "+nombre+ " " + papellido + " " + sapellido + " ,con dirección " +direccion + " ,/n vive en " +poblacion+ " y cumple años dentro de " + (12 - periodo.getMonths()) + " meses y " + (30 - periodo.getDays()) + " dias");
    }
}
```

Comment: Me da este error: Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: Listo, le hice unos cambios, ya lo probe debe funcionar, intentele y me comenta.